# Concurrency in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn Ruby on rails following the "Agile Web Development with Rails" book. In the book. I haven't got far yet but I have this question. I have been building web-apps from the book that refer to "one user". For example, in the book it says "if the user clicks this... if the user enters this...", and so on.

What happens when I got 1000 users? or 100000 users? How does ruby on rails in combination with sqlite (that I am using.) deals with the concurrency? Do I assume the user is one, and continue building the web-app and ruby takes care of the concurrency automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails work just like any other system. Each request is processed in serial, to process multiple requests in parallel, you (usually) use multiple servers (either multiple physical/virtual hosts, or run the app multiple times on one box). 1000 (or 100000) users clicking on a link just implies 1000 (or 100000) requests to your server that get processed in series (parallel with load balancing on multiple servers).

For the DB, you usually wouldn't use Sqlite for a production web server, and systems like MySql take care of concurrency in requests by themselves (note that queries are usually stateless, so once a SQL server handles a query, it can usually discard the state associated with it)